# how button click event works in combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically append options in a combo box.

How does button click event work in a combo box element? I am using change event. But I need button click event in the combo box. How can I 'uniquify' the combo box element in jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by `uniquify`? Why do you need the `click` event when everyone is using the `change` event? What are you trying to do different than others?

Comment: @shef; I am trying to add option dynamiclally.. So, there an element -add- in the combobox. When I click it it shows me a confirm box. On click the cancel in doing nothing But again I click add in the combo box nothing happens because option in the combo box doesnot changes

Comment: Can you post an example of your current code? Ideally at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what you mean.

Comment: You could just use the change event and do a quick test to see whether the value is -add-

Comment: Do you mean a `<select>` element?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, add a button to add options to a combo box.

OR, add a default option like:

`<option value="default">Make a choice...</option>`

Then if a user cancels the dialog box, change the selected option on the combo box to `default`. So, when they want to add another option, they will have to click on the drop down box to choose the `- add -` option again.